# Change thread priority

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-priority

I am trying to change the priority of a thread but I can't get it to work. I have made a button which toggles the priority between low and high and when I am checking this in the joblist the priority is changed. But the CPU usage isn't changed. I wonder if this is just because I don't use the full CPU power or how this can be.

I am not asking if it is a good idea. I am asking how to do it.

Here is how I change the priority. This is the code behind class:

```
    private Thread tr;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(infiniteLoop));
        tr.Start();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass == ProcessPriorityClass.High)
        {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;
            tr.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
            description.Text = "Idle";
        }

        else
        {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
            tr.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            description.Text = "High";
        }
    }

    private void infiniteLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to mess with thread or process priorities.

Comment: @Nicholas Butler: Oh, I see, Microsoft made thread management API public just for fun :)

Comment: I know but I realy want to know how to change it properly at runtime

Comment: @IgorKorkhov He said *generally*, not *unconditionally*. This question is tagged with `wpf` - which doesn't scream "I need advanced thread scheduling" to me.

Comment: It does have its uses.  In environments where the machine is regularly fully loaded/overloaded, (ie. when the number of ready threads is often larger than the number of CPU cores), raising the priority an I/O-bound process/threads can help the process maintain tight throughput/latency targets while minimally affecting other CPU-intensive apps that don't have such hard limits.  Many OS apply priority boosts anyway to threads that become ready after an I/O driver interrupt, just to promote this optimization automatically.

Comment: At least, the OP tried something and asked why it did not work as anticipated - a good way to learn.  A 'general' appreciation of thread states, scheduling algorithms, synchro primitives etc. is not really 'advanced scheduling' - it's something all developers, (OK, not bash scripters:), should know about at a basic level and is too often lacking.  Just how many poor 'sleep(0)', 'sleep(1)' and 'yield()' solutions have been posted here, I wonder...

Comment: @FireFly3000 - changing priorities at thread start time is a resonable optimization in some circumstances with some apps.  I have never changed the priority of a thread at any other time.

Comment: I have updated the priority of threads which are responsible for low level comms to Highest in the past without ill effects (in high multithreaded apps). E.g. comms which are responsible for controlling hardware - you would want a comms thread command to stop a robotic arm from moving take precedence to a higher level command to check its position for example.

Comment: Just to note: It is very rare I do this, and should be treated with extreme caution (e.g. prevent thread starvation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work how I think you expect it to - i.e. that a process with low priority is somehow throttled to x% CPU time.

A single-threaded process with any priority can consume 100% of CPU time on one core.

When you have two processes, one with higher priority than the other, that would both consume 100% CPU time on their own, executing simultaneously, the one with higher priority will get all of the CPU time (assuming a single core) and the one with lower priority will not progress at all.

The priority of a process is simply used to determine the order in which the scheduler will "hand out" CPU time slices to processes.

Comment: oh... I just realised that I have 4 cores in my computer.... the process is using 25%. So compared to what you say it is using 100% on one core which was exeactly what you told.

Comment: Yep, that's right. If you want a single process to be able to use multiple CPUs effectively, use multiple threads. System.Threading.Tasks is great for this in .NET 4.0, makes things much simpler than plain old System.Threading.